# How to get json data from multiple object levels

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I need to create a table from selected data generated by some rental software in json format via an api.  The json data supplied is a list of products, and is quite extensive with objects containing other objects and arrays.

The problem comes when I need to retrieve the data from an object within an object.  I want to get Name, weight and Rental Price form the data below.  The rental price is in the rental_rate object.

```
{
"products": [
{
  "id": 1404,
  "name": "Product 1",
  "type": "Product",
  "tag_list": [],
  "description": "",
  "allowed_stock_type": 1,
  "allowed_stock_type_name": "Rental",
  "stock_method": 1,
  "stock_method_name": "Bulk",
  "buffer_percent": "50.0",
  "post_rent_unavailability": 0,
  "replacement_charge": "0.0",
  "weight": "0.5",
  "barcode": "@st2078",
  "active": true,
  "accessory_only": false,
  "system": false,
  "discountable": true,
  "rental_rate": {
    "item_id": 1404,
    "store_id": 1,
    "transaction_type": 1,
    "rate_definition_id": 3,
    "price": "10.0",
    "deposit": "0.0",
    "category_prices": [],
    "properties": {
      "day_cost": "0.0",
      "day_price": "0.0",
      "hour_cost": "0.0",
      "hour_price": "0.0",
      "__value_types": "---\nday_price: BigDecimal\nhour_price: BigDecimal\ndistance_price: BigDecimal\nflat_rate_price: BigDecimal\nday_cost: BigDecimal\nhour_cost: BigDecimal\ndistance_cost: BigDecimal\nflat_rate_cost: BigDecimal\n",
      "distance_cost": "0.0",
      "distance_price": "0.0",
      "flat_rate_cost": "0.0",
      "flat_rate_price": "0.0"
    },
    "priority": 0,
    "date_range": "1900-01-01...3000-01-01"
  },
  "sale_rate": null,
  "product_group_id": 5,
  "tax_class_id": 2,
  "rental_revenue_group_id": 1,
  "sale_revenue_group_id": null,
  "created_at": "2017-02-06T00:49:47.755Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-02-06T00:49:47.755Z",
  "custom_fields": {
    "barcode_notes": "Actual Leg Length is: 3'",
    "product_serial_number": ""
  },
  "product_group": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Staging",
    "description": "",
    "created_at": "2017-02-05T22:20:53.465Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-05T22:20:53.465Z",
    "custom_fields": {}
  },
  "tax_class": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "VAT Standard"
  },
  "icon": null,
  "rental_revenue_group": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Rental",
    "description": "",
    "active": true
  },
  "sale_revenue_group": null,
  "accessories": [],
  "alternative_products": [],
  "attachments": [],
  "rental_rates": [
    {
      "id": 1782,
      "store_id": null,
      "store_name": "",
      "rate_definition_id": 3,
      "rate_definition_name": "3 Day Week Rate",
      "starts_at": null,
      "ends_at": null,
      "price": "10.0",
      "category_prices": []
    }
  ],
  "sale_rates": []
},
{
  "id": 2395,
  "name": "Product 2",
  "type": "Product",
  "tag_list": [],
  "description": "",
  "allowed_stock_type": 1,
  "allowed_stock_type_name": "Rental",
  "stock_method": 2,x
  "stock_method_name": "Serialised",
  "buffer_percent": "50.0",
  "post_rent_unavailability": 0,
  "replacement_charge": "0.0",
  "weight": "45.0",
  "barcode": "",
  "active": true,
  "accessory_only": false,
  "system": false,
  "discountable": true,
  "rental_rate": {
    "item_id": 2395,
    "store_id": 1,
    "transaction_type": 1,
    "rate_definition_id": 3,
    "price": "0.0",
    "deposit": "0.0",
    "category_prices": [],
    "properties": {
      "day_cost": "0.0",
      "day_price": "0.0",
      "hour_cost": "0.0",
      "hour_price": "0.0",
      "__value_types": "---\nday_price: BigDecimal\nhour_price: BigDecimal\ndistance_price: BigDecimal\nflat_rate_price: BigDecimal\nday_cost: BigDecimal\nhour_cost: BigDecimal\ndistance_cost: BigDecimal\nflat_rate_cost: BigDecimal\n",
      "distance_cost": "0.0",
      "distance_price": "0.0",
      "flat_rate_cost": "0.0",
      "flat_rate_price": "0.0"
    },
    "priority": 0,
    "date_range": "1900-01-01...3000-01-01"
  },
  "sale_rate": null,
  "product_group_id": 6,
  "tax_class_id": 2,
  "rental_revenue_group_id": 1,
  "sale_revenue_group_id": null,
  "created_at": "2017-02-06T00:50:35.834Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-02-06T00:50:35.834Z",
  "custom_fields": {
    "barcode_notes": "",
    "product_serial_number": ""
  },
  "product_group": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Cases",
    "description": "",
    "created_at": "2017-02-05T22:20:53.509Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-05T22:20:53.509Z",
    "custom_fields": {}
  },
  "tax_class": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "VAT Standard"
  },
  "icon": null,
  "rental_revenue_group": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Rental",
    "description": "",
    "active": true
  },
  "sale_revenue_group": null,
  "accessories": [],
  "alternative_products": [],
  "attachments": [],
  "rental_rates": [
    {
      "id": 2773,
      "store_id": null,
      "store_name": "",
      "rate_definition_id": 3,
      "rate_definition_name": "3 Day Week Rate",
      "starts_at": null,
      "ends_at": null,
      "price": "0.0",
      "category_prices": []
    }
  ],
  "sale_rates": []
}
  ],
 "meta": {
"total_row_count": 1376,
"row_count": 2,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 2
   }
  }
```

and here is the JS I am using to get the data:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$.getJSON( 'https://myapi.com/products', function(data) { 
  $.each(data.products, function() { 
     $("table#prod").append("<tr><td>" + this['name'] + "</td><td>" + this['rental_rate.price'] + "</td><td>" + this['weight'] + "kg</td></tr>");
  }); }); });
```

This works fine for name and weight, but not rental price.  I have done a thorough search of most places on the internet and not found an answer - my javascript knowledge is limited, which probably means I am going about this all wrong, or not describing it well enough...
Any help or improved methods would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need `this['rental_rate']['price']` or `this.rental_rate['price']` or `this.rental_rate.price` Two minutes of basic research would've yielded this information.

Comment: @ChrisG - is it possible to downvote a comment?

Comment: @Adam No. Two minutes of basic research would've yielded this information.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I think this was down to me not understanding what the square braces meant, so I was searching for the wrong question.  I now know more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.name` gets you the name

`this.rental_rate` gets you the nested rental rate object.

`this.rental_rate.price` gets you the price.

You can similarly use [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), but people often only do this when dot syntax won't work (because of spaces in the `key`).

e.g.

`this["name"]`

`this["rental_rate"]["price"]`

`this["Invalid Key when accessed via dot syntax but fine with square brackets"]`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Adam, and for solving my problem.  I had totally misunderstood what I was doing!